# Where can I find a list of fonts that go in the constructor 'public Font( string familyName, float emSize )'?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, fonts, system.drawing

I've been trying for the past  hour to figure out where I can get a list of all possible values that go into `familyName` in the constructor

```
public Font(
    string familyName,
    float emSize
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm trying to find a font that is close to the thin

```
wf_segoe-ui_semilight,wf_segoe-ui_light,wf_segoe-ui_normal,'Segoe UI Semilight','Segoe UI Light','Segoe UI',Arial,sans-serif !important
```

on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/

and so far I've been doing the "Guess and check" method where I recompile my application after putting in a new font name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the FontFamily class

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplicationFont
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var item in FontFamily.Families)
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the idea that there's a `Familes` property of `FontFamily`.

Comment: `Windows.System.Media.FontFamily does not contain a definition for Families` Maybe MSDN is outdated?

Comment: The namespace is System.Drawing,run my example

Comment: Copy-pasting the above gives `The name 'FontFamily' does not exist in the current context`. I can get VS to recognize `FontFamily` is I include `using System.Windows.Media` but then the `Families` property isn't recognized.

Comment: Add a reference to System.Drawing.dll

Comment: You, sir, get a gold start. Best answer and I'll go upvote a bunch of your answers from other threads.

Comment: @SubparWebDev Seriously thanks,but there is no reason to do that. When you upvote/downvote an answer don't see who posted it.Review just the answer